# Adjust the Table

Tags: tables, errors

I use generating table web https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ but it shows `undefined control sequence } after    \end{tabular}%.` I tried to delete it but resulting a more error. Do you have any suggestion how to solve this error?

Thank you

```
\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{\textbf{Parameter}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.4}$Zr$_{0.6}$NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.5}$Zr$_{0.5}$NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.6}$Zr$_{0.4}$NiSn}}                                     \\ \cline{2-7} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                    & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Ti}                                               & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     & 18.20         & 3.13                                                                     & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Zr}                                               & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     & 18.62         & 3.85                                                                     & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Ni}                                               & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     & 30.76         & 3.17                                                                     & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Sn}                                               & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     & 32.42         & 3.04                                                                     & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Stoickhiometry}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$_{0.45}$Zr$_{0.64}$Ni$_{0.94}$Sn$_{0.97}$}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$_{0.55}$Zr$_{0.56}$Ni$_{0.92} $Sn$_{0.97}$}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$ _{0.57} $Zr$ _{0.48} $Ni$ _{0.98} $Sn$ _{0.96}$}}                                   \\ \hline

            \textbf{Phase 1 ($\%$Area)}                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.19} $Zr$ _{0.8} $Ni$ _{1.03} $Sn$ _{0.97} (79.15$\%$) $}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.32} $Zr$ _{0.68} $Ni$ _{1.03} $Sn$ _{0.98} $ (69.79$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.38} $Zr$ _{0.61} $Ni$ _{1.07} $Sn$ _{0.94} $ (55.06$\%$)}                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{Phase 2 ($\%$Area}                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$_{1.18}  $Zr$ _{0.23} $Ni$ {_0.44} $Sn$ _{1.14} $ (20.85$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$_{1.03}  $Zr$ _{0.25} $Ni$_ {0.34}$Sn$_{1.54}  $(30.21$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{1.45} $Zr$ _{0.27} $Ni$ _{0.16} $Sn$ _{1.12} $(44.94$\%$)}                                            \\ \hline
        \textbf{Grain size}                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17.15$\mu$m}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{25.77$\mu$m}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19.53$\mu$m}                                                                   \\ \hline

            \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: The usage of the `\multirow` command is wrong as the first two arguments missing: `\multirow{<number of rows>}{<width>}{<content>}`. Also I'd recommend against the usage of `resizebox` in order to make the table fit into the textwidth as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the `booktabs` package and the recommendation against using vertical lines. Personally, I'd also not use bold entries. Lastly, you might also want to have a look at the `mhchem` package that might make typesetting the contents of your "Stoickhiometry"  (did you mean "Stoichiometry" instead?) a lot easier.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an answer that is, at first glance, very similar to [the one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498979/5001) posted by @leandriis. E.g., it doesn't use **bold-facing**, it uses no vertical rules and only few but well-spaced horizontal rules (using the macros of the `booktabs` package), it employs the `\ce` macro (by the `mhchem` package) to enter chemical formulas and the `\SI` macro (by the `siunitx` package) to enter scientific units and their associated quantities.

My answer differs mainly in the provision of more structure to the header material and the splitting off of area-related information onto separate rows. It also employs a `tabularx` column, to assure that all six data columns have equal width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,mhchem,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mx[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{#1}}  % for final col.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Parameter & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{As cast}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
&\mc{\ce{Ti_{0.4}Zr_{0.6}NiSn}}  
&\mc{\ce{Ti_{0.5}Zr_{0.5}NiSn}} 
&\mx{\ce{Ti_{0.6}Zr_{0.4}NiSn}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& Atom & Rel.\ error 
& Atom & Rel.\ error 
& Atom & Rel.\ error \\ 
& (\%) & (\%, $1\sigma$) 
& (\%) & (\%, $1\sigma$) 
& (\%) & (\%, $1\sigma$) \\
\midrule
Ti   & 15.13 & 3.20 & 18.20 & 3.13 & 15.13 & 3.20 \\ \addlinespace
Zr   & 20.89 & 3.84 & 18.62 & 3.85 & 20.89 & 3.84 \\ \addlinespace
Ni   & 31.53 & 3.17 & 30.76 & 3.17 & 31.53 & 3.17 \\ \addlinespace
Sn   & 32.44 & 3.05 & 32.42 & 3.04 & 32.44 & 3.05 \\ 
\midrule
Stoichiometry           
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{0.45}Zr_{0.64}Ni_{0.94}Sn_{0.97}}}
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{0.55}Zr_{0.56}Ni_{0.92}Sn_{0.97}}}           
& \mx{\ce{Ti_{0.57}Zr_{0.48}Ni_{0.98}Sn_{0.96}}} \\ 
\addlinespace
Phase 1      
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{0.19}Zr_{0.8}Ni_{1.03}Sn_{0.97}}}         
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{0.32}Zr_{0.68}Ni_{1.03}Sn_{0.98}}}        
& \mx{\ce{Ti_{0.38}Zr_{0.61}Ni_{1.07}Sn_{0.94}}} \\ 
\% Area & \mc{79.15\%} & \mc{69.79\%} & \mc{55.06\%}\\
\addlinespace
Phase 2     
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{1.18}Zr_{0.23}Ni_{0.44}Sn_{1.14}}}
& \mc{\ce{Ti_{1.03}Zr_{0.25}Ni_{0.34}Sn_{1.54}}}
& \mx{\ce{Ti_{1.45}Zr_{0.27}Ni_{0.16}Sn_{1.12}}}\\ 
\% Area & \mc{20.85\%} & \mc{30.21\%} & \mc{44.94\%}\\
\addlinespace
Grain size 
& \mc{\SI{17.15}{\micro\meter}}       
& \mc{\SI{25.77}{\micro\meter}}       
& \mx{\SI{19.53}{\micro\meter}} \\ 
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make your code compilable, I have added the `graphicx` and the `multirow` package. I have also corrected the wrong use of the `\multirow` command that wat missing its first two arguments: `\multirow{<number of rows>}{<width>}{<content>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Parameter}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.4}$Zr$_{0.6}$NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.5}$Zr$_{0.5}$NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{As cast Ti$_{0.6}$Zr$_{0.4}$NiSn}}                                     \\ \cline{2-7} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                    & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Atom ($\%$)} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rel. error ($\%$) \\ (1 sigma)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Ti}                                               & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     & 18.20         & 3.13                                                                     & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Zr}                                               & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     & 18.62         & 3.85                                                                     & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Ni}                                               & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     & 30.76         & 3.17                                                                     & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Sn}                                               & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     & 32.42         & 3.04                                                                     & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     \\ \hline
            \textbf{Stoickhiometry}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$_{0.45}$Zr$_{0.64}$Ni$_{0.94}$Sn$_{0.97}$}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$_{0.55}$Zr$_{0.56}$Ni$_{0.92} $Sn$_{0.97}$}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ti$ _{0.57} $Zr$ _{0.48} $Ni$ _{0.98} $Sn$ _{0.96}$}}                                   \\ \hline

            \textbf{Phase 1 ($\%$Area)}                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.19} $Zr$ _{0.8} $Ni$ _{1.03} $Sn$ _{0.97} (79.15$\%$) $}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.32} $Zr$ _{0.68} $Ni$ _{1.03} $Sn$ _{0.98} $ (69.79$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{0.38} $Zr$ _{0.61} $Ni$ _{1.07} $Sn$ _{0.94} $ (55.06$\%$)}                                            \\ \hline
            \textbf{Phase 2 ($\%$Area}                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$_{1.18}  $Zr$ _{0.23} $Ni$ {_0.44} $Sn$ _{1.14} $ (20.85$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$_{1.03}  $Zr$ _{0.25} $Ni$_ {0.34}$Sn$_{1.54}  $(30.21$\%$)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ti$ _{1.45} $Zr$ _{0.27} $Ni$ _{0.16} $Sn$ _{1.12} $(44.94$\%$)}                                            \\ \hline
        \textbf{Grain size}                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{17.15$\mu$m}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{25.77$\mu$m}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{19.53$\mu$m}                                                                   \\ \hline

            \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

There are however quite some things that can be done to improve the look of the table. First of all, don't use `resizebox` in order to make your table fit into the textwidth as this will lead to inconsistent (and sometimes illegibly small) font sizes. Instead you can change the font size to `\small` and decrease the horizontal space between columns using `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}` (default is 6pt). I have also introduced linebreaks in the "Phase 1" and "phase 2" rows to save some more horizontal space.

To get a less cramped table, I recommend removing all vertical lines and replacing the horizonral lines y the rules from the `booktabs` package or just some vertical white space. Also, I have removed all bold from the table.

To improve the typesetting of chemical elements and subscript numbers, I have used the `mhchem` package and its `\ce` command instead of math mode. Lastly, I have also introduced the `siunitx` package for adding the units in the last table row (and removed some typos):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering \small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
            \toprule
            Parameter & \multicolumn{2}{c}{As cast \ce{Ti_{0.4}Zr_{0.6}NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{As cast \ce{Ti_{0.5}Zr_{0.5}NiSn}}                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{As cast \ce{Ti_{0.6}Zr_{0.4}NiSn}}                                     \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
             & Atom (\%) & Rel. error (\%) & Atom ($\%$) & Rel. error (\%) & Atom (\%) & Rel. error ($\%$) \\ 
          &  &  (1 sigma) & & (1 sigma) & & (1 sigma) \\
            \midrule
            Ti                                               & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     & 18.20         & 3.13                                                                     & 15.13         & 3.20                                                                     \\ 
            Zr                                               & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     & 18.62         & 3.85                                                                     & 20.89         & 3.84                                                                     \\ 
            Ni                                               & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     & 30.76         & 3.17                                                                     & 31.53         & 3.17                                                                     \\ 
            Sn                                               & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     & 32.42         & 3.04                                                                     & 32.44         & 3.05                                                                     \\ \addlinespace
            Stoichiometry                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.45}Zr_{0.64}Ni_{0.94}Sn_{0.97}}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.55}Zr_{0.56}Ni_{0.92} Sn_{0.97}}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.57}Zr_{0.48}Ni_{0.98}Sn_{0.96}}}                                   \\ 
\addlinespace
            Phase 1 (\% Area)                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.19}Zr_{0.8}Ni_{1.03}Sn_{0.97}}}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.32}Zr_{0.68}Ni_{1.03}Sn_{0.98}}}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{0.38}Zr_{0.61}Ni_{1.07}Sn_{0.94}}}                                            \\ 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(79.15\%)}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(69.79\%)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(55.06\%)}  \\
            \addlinespace
        Phase 2 (\%Area                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{1.18}Zr_{0.23}Ni_{0.44}Sn_{1.14}}}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{1.03}Zr_{0.25}Ni_{0.34}Sn_{1.54}}}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ce{Ti_{1.45}Zr_{0.27}Ni_{0.16}Sn_{1.12}}}                                           \\ 
            Phase 2 (\%Area                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(20.85\%)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(30.21\%)}                                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(44.94\%)}                                           \\ \addlinespace
        Grain size                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{17.15}{\micro\meter}}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{25.77}{\micro\meter}}                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{19.53}{\micro\meter}}                                                                   \\ \bottomrule

            \end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `\adjustbox` with tables to avoid inconsistent font sizes. I propose to use a smaller font size, reduce the intercolumn spacing and load `geometry` to have more decent margins (if you do not use marginal notes). I added some improvements and code simplification, with the `makecell`, `siunitx` and `chemformula` packages. Multirow is not needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadset} {\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries As cast} \\[1ex]
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries \ch{Ti_{0.6}Zr_{0.5}NiSn}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\ch{Ti_{0.5}Zr_{0.5}NiSn}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\ch{Ti_{0.6}Zr_{0.4}NiSn}} \\ \cline{2-7}
        \hline
        \thead[l]{Parameter} & \thead{Atom \\(\%)} & \thead{Rel. error \\(\%) (1 sigma)} & \thead{Atom \\(\%)} & \thead{Rel. error\\ (\%) (1 sigma)} & \thead{Atom \\(\%)} & \thead{Rel. error \\($\%$) (1 sigma)} \\
        \hline
       Ti & 15.13 & 3.20 & 18.20 & 3.13 & 15.13 & 3.20 \\
        \hline
        Zr & 20.89 & 3.84 & 18.62 & 3.85 & 20.89 & 3.84 \\
        \hline
        Ni & 31.53 & 3.17 & 30.76 & 3.17 & 31.53 & 3.17 \\
        \hline
        Sn & 32.44 & 3.05 & 32.42 & 3.04 & 32.44 & 3.05 \\
        \hline
        Stoichiometry & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries\ch{Ti_{0.45}Zr_{0.64}Ni_{0.94} Sn_{0.97}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries\ch{Ti_{0.55}Zr_{0.56}Ni_{0.92} Sn_{0.97}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries\ch{Ti_{0.57}Zr_{0.48}Ni_{0.98} Sn_{0.96}}} \\
        \hline
        \thead[l]{Phase 1 \\(\% Area)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\ch{Ti_{0.19}Zr_{0.8}Ni_{1.03} Sn_{0.97}}\\[0.5ex] (79.15\,\%) }} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{ \ch{Ti_{0.32}Zr_{0.68}Ni_{1.03} Sn_{0.98}}\\[0.5ex] (69.79\,\%)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\ch{Ti_{0.38}Zr_{0.61}Ni_{1.07} Sn_{0.94}}\\[0.5ex] (55.06\,\%)}} \\
        \hline
        \thead[l]{Phase 2\\ (\% Area)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\ch{Ti_{1.18}Zr_{0.23}Ni_{0.44} Sn_{1.14}}\\[0.5ex] (20.85\,\,\%)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\ch{Ti_{1.03}Zr_{0.25}Ni_{0.34} Sn_{1.54}}\\[0.5ex] (30.21\,\%)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\ch{Ti_{1.45}Zr_{0.27}Ni_{0.16} Sn_{1.12}}\\[0.5ex] (44.94\,\%)}} \\
        \hline
     Grain size & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\SI{17.15}{\um}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\SI{25.77}{\um}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\SI{19.53}{\um}} \\
    \hline
        \end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]